# Make application runnable

Tags: .desktop, activities-overview, anki

I just installed Anki v2.1.49, I can run it from terminal with `bin/Anki` but I would like to make it runnable with <kbd>Super</kbd> -> Anki and set it as a shortcut (*e.g.* runnable from <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>).

I think I may have to use `.desktop` file. They provide one, but it doesn't seem to be recognized by Ubuntu. Here is the content of the `~/anki-2.1.49-linux` file:

```
joris@joris-N751JK:~/anki-2.1.49-linux$ ls
anki.1  anki.desktop  anki.png  anki.xml  anki.xpm  bin  install.sh  README  uninstall.sh
```

Comment: What was wrong with officially [packaged version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/anki)?

Comment: This is not the one I downloaded. I downloaded the one from their [official website](https://apps.ankiweb.net/)

Comment: Using deb-package is always simpler and more reliable. You are using windows method on Ubuntu. And it does not matter that official package is a bit newer...

Comment: It seems to me that debian package is v2.1.15 vs v2.1.49 for the version from their website. Isn't that quite a large difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this application, but chances are that running the `install.sh` script will set up everything automatically for you. Drag the icon from within the Application Overview to the third position of the dock to add it as a favourite. You will then be able to run it using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

If after installation, the icon of the application does not appear in the Applications overview, then the `install.sh` script may not have (correctly) installed the application in the menu system. You can do so yourself by copying the `.desktop` launcher in your `~/.local/share/applications` directory. Once placed there, it will be picked up in the applications overview.

If, after all of the above, the application still does not appear in the Application Overview, you will need to check and eventually edit the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`.

- `Exec=` line should point to the actual file path of the executable
- `Icon=` line should point to an actual `.png` or `.xpm` icon file. Better yet, copy the icon to `~/.local/share/icons`. Then, you only need to specify the name of the graphics file, *without* file path and *without* extension, for it to be found.

Comment: Thanks, does that require reboot?

Comment: You can always play safe and reboot. Even only login out and back in is "playing safe". In practice, a desktop file is automatically picked up within seconds after it has been installed (or has been corrected - note that an invalid .desktop file, e.g. invalid path, will not appear in the overview ever.

Comment: There was originally a `%f` at the end of the `Exec=` line. What is it? Should I keep it? (as a side note, there is also a `TryExec=` line)

Comment: Yes you should keep that

Comment: It solved my problem, thank you!